Config spark to default read dat from hdfs
I've installed HDFS and Spark. However, how can I configure Spark to read from hdfs://localhost:9000/ by default? Currently, to load a file into a Spark DataFrame, I need to write spark.read.load("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dat/test.txt"). Ideally, I'd like to simplify this to spark.read.load("/user/dat/test.txt") while still being able to read local files using spark.read.load("file:///...local_dir...")
Where is the configuration file for this, and how do I set it up?

In the configured environment variable of SPARK_CONF_DIR, you may have a spark-env.sh file that defines a HADOOP_CONF_DIR. In that directory, you can define a hdfs-site.xml file that contains
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#overriding-configuration-directory
